# How to monitor updated values of three <select>

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I work with codeigniter and have the following problem.

In the controller (results.php), I have something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['tournaments'])){
$tournament_id = $_POST['tournaments'];
}else{
$tournament_id=1;
}

if( isset($_POST['categories'])){
$category_id = $_POST['categories'];
}else{
$category_id=1;
}

if( isset($_POST['groups'])){
$group_id = $_POST['groups'];       
}else{
$group_id=1;
}
//returns a list of tournaments (id and name)
$data['tournaments'] = $this->tournaments_model->getTournaments(); 

if($data['tournaments']>0){
//returns a list of categories where tournament=$tournament_id (id and name)
$data['categories'] = $this->tournaments_model->getCategories($tournament_id); 
if($data['categories']>0){
//returns a list of groups where where tournament=$tournament_id and category=$category_id
$data['groups'] = $this->tournaments_model->getGroup($tournament_id,$category_id);
}
}
//returns info about team ranking, etc. 
if($data['tournaments']>0 && $data['categories']>0 && $data['groups']>0){
$data['rows'] = $this->tournaments_model->getAll($tournament_id, $category_id, $group_id);

if($data['rows']>0){
$this->load->view('header_view', $data);
$this->load->view('results_view', $data);
$this->load->view('footer_view');   
}else{
$this->load->view('header_view', $data);
$this->load->view('norecords_view');
$this->load->view('footer_view');
}   
}
```

The view(results_view.php), outputs something like this:
(changed tags with quotes)

```
"form"
"select name="tournaments" id="tournament""
"option value="1" selected="selected">A Tournament""
"option value="2">B Tournament"
"option value="3">C Tournament"

"select name="categories" id="category""
"option value="1" selected="selected">Junior"
"option value="6" >Pro-Junior"

"select name="groups" id="group"
"option value="1" selected="selected">A Group"
"option value="2">B Group"
```

So, this should set three fields to: 
    $_POST['tournaments'] = 1
    $_POST['categories']) = 1
    $_POST['group']) = 1

What I want to do is:
Pass these values to the controller without submitting the form with button.
Apart from that, when "Tournament" changes (e.g from 1 to 2), this should bring other data for the "Category" and "Group".
For example:
 selected:      Tournament_id=1
    then            Category_id=1, 
                 Group_id=1
                Category_id=2
                 Group_id=2
                 Group_id=3

selected:      Tournament_id=2
    then            Category_id=1
                    Group_id=1
                    Group_id=2

That means, somehow I have to monitor the update of all three $_POST fields, send them back to the controller 
and fetch new data from my sql query in the model.
I tried something with jquery, but didn't get the result I wanted.

I suppose, there should be a function that would monitor the change of any of three "select".
[controller-view interaction](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B15bmK58VaEedGRORWtqc2xzTG8)

If you have any idea how to do this, please give some advice. 
Thanks.

These are my controller(results.php) and view (results_view.php)
[scripts](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B15bmK58VaEeS3A5ek01bHhzeTQ/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$("form select").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("results_view.php", $(this).parent().serialize(), function() {
        // update form from JSON data
    });
});
```

Comment: If I understand well, this will send the values from the form on results_view.php to results_view.php. This won't work. The values should be send to results.php (controller), because they are used as parameters in the model queries. 
That's where I stuck. How to bring new data for <select id='Category'> from controller.

Comment: The controller needs to return results using `json_encode()`, and then the "update form from JSON data" code can insert use jQuery to update things. The [jQuery.populate](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html) plugin may be useful.